# Passing lifecycle to child composables

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it a good approach to pass information about current lifecycle down to child composables as parameter?

In my parent composable, I declared variable to remember current lifecycle and I pass it down to children composables.

Comment: It might be worth to include an example or an explanation why your children composables need to have access to that information